# Opening PDF in Lightbox/Fancy Box etc From Flash AS2

Tags: jquery, flash, fancybox, actionscript-2, lightbox

Ive been looking this up and i just have had no luck correctly implementing this. How can i open a pdf file in lightbox like thing (ie. fancybox etc)? I would also be linking this from Flash AS2

Any help?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808586/1055987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to do what you ask in some browsers, you will not get a consistent result in all browsers. There is also the issue of PDF reader plugins that may or may not be installed.

For example: Chrome (without a browser plugin) can open pdf's in an iframe, while Internet Explorer (without plugins) will open the iframe, but then it will use whatever program .pdf's are associated with to open the file anyways. The iframe will remain blank. And as I said, all this changes wildly once you take plugins into account.

My advice is to treat the pdf-file as a simple downloadable file and let the users decide for them selves how to view it.