# fancybox pdf not working in google chrome

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, pdf, iframe, fancybox

Fancybox PDF (iFrame) loads in all browsers except Chrome.  The loading gif stays forever, but never loads anything, however, the photos and videos work fine.

```
$(function() {
    $(".fancypdf").fancybox({
            padding : 5,
            framewidth : 855,
            frameheight : 470,
            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 'normal',
            openEasing : 'easeOutBack',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 'normal',
            closeEasing : 'easeInBack',
            closeClick : true,
            type:'iframe',
});
```

Also, on the ipad, the dimensions of the PDF are off.  Width is correct, but height is about 200px and can't scroll.  Everything else works fine.

[Link here](http://www.juliandiazvelosa.com/press.html)

Any help would be great! Thanks!!

Comment: It seems to be a PDF issue because when I link the fancybox iframe to a webpage, it opens fine.  Is there an issue with fancy pdf's and chrome?

Comment: Answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803927/displaying-pdfs-in-jquery-popup